# Why isn't my Object Inspector showing help for the current property?

Tags: delphi

I am using Delphi XE2 with help installed.

I want to see the hints for specific properties when they are selected in the Object Inspector, but they do not appear. How do I make it work?

[image: Screenshot]

It just says "Caption" at the bottom without describing the property.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting. That's not a hint window, AFAICT; it simply shows you the name of the selected property. (You can check this by using the scrollbar to move the `Caption` out of sight.) I tested with both XE and D2010, and they both have the same behavior.

Comment: @Ken Have a look at the VS designer and you'll see that it provides a little help text in the equivalent place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a feature that the Delphi Object Inspector does not implement. Visual Studio has that capability. Perhaps you are used to that and expected to see the same in Delphi.

To find out information about a property, select it and press F1.

Comment: Then why it is there ,wasting my space

Comment: You mean, why is the selected property name shown at the bottom of the inspector in bold? I don't know.

Comment: I always resize it to be almost invisible. Too bad that IDE can't remember this next time I launch it.

Comment: That "infobox" was introduced with the C# IDE personality (which is long gone) where the properties used it. The VCL never used it for anything.

Comment: But it was not there in delphi 2009 and previous IDEs , but C# IDE came with delphi 2006